# Selenium How to avoid using selector in the script

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and C# for automation scripts.

To avoid using too many selectors in the script, I'd like to write a common method like:

```
 public static void SelectItem(this IWebElement elementBlade, string itemName)

        {
            IList<IWebElement> itemList = new List<IWebElement>();

            if (elementBlade.Text  == "MainPage")
            {
                itemList = elementBlade.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".search-item-container .item-description"));
            }

            else if(elementBlade.Text == "LoginPage" || elementBlade.Text == "UserColumnSelectedblade")
            {
                itemList = elementBlade.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".item-description"));
            }

            ............

         }
```

But seems it's not working, any other way I could achieve this, please?

Comment: Can you add `HTML` related to `elementBlade` and it's child nodes?

Comment: @Fenio Thanks for reply..I use different elementBlade in different classes, so how to add HTML pls?

Comment: Then add the one that fails

Comment: @Fenio public IWebElement MainPage => DriverFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("main")); This is one elementBlade

Comment: Add snippet of HTML